# Invalid IPA: missing embedded provisioning profile. Are you sure this is an ad hoc?

Tags: ios, xcode, maven-plugin, ipa

I have searched a lot on internet but non of the solutions work for me. I create an ipa with [Xcode Maven Plugin](http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/index.html) It successfully builds my application and creates an ipa but when I want to upload it on testflightapp it gives me this error:

```
Invalid IPA: missing embedded provisioning profile. Are you sure this is an ad hoc?
```

I have added provisioning profile in build settings like the following pic
[image]

If I create ipa manually with Xcode>Product>Archive I can successfully upload ipa on testflightapp. So my guess is that Xcode Maven Plugin cannot read my provisioning profile. I tried to force using provisioning profile by specifying it in pom file like bellow:

```
<configuration>
          <configurations>
            <configuration>Debug</configuration>
            <configuration>Release</configuration>
          </configurations>
          <provisioningProfile>42CB38B0-62BB-4242-BD03-72EDB7570842</provisioningProfile>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was using wrong ipa file from maven target. I was using ipa from this path:

```
/target/checkout/src/xcode/build/Debug-iphonesimulator
```

I had to use this path

```
/target/checkout/src/xcode/build/Release-iphoneos
```

It was stupid mistake.

Answer (score 14):

I changed build system to Legacy Build System and it was resolved.
To change it go to File -> Workspace Settings
[image]

Comment: I needed to do this for a phonegap v8.0.0 app. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question but may help others.

From the screenshot I see you have selected iPhone device and not **Generic iOS Device** that's why it is giving you provisioning profile error.

Select Generic iOS device and then build the project.

I got this error and it catches my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that while creating an **.ipa** file you must need to select **Generic iOS Device** as a **Target**

[image]/i.stack.imgur.com/LsqBS.png