# Uploading IPA file into diawi.com

Tags: c++, ios, qt

While uploading ipa package into https://www.diawi.com/ gives an error "Invalid IPA: missing embedded provision". In Xcode app got build successfully and successfully run in the simulator

Comment: Did you checked [Invalid IPA: missing embedded provisioning profile. Are you sure this is an ad hoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428519/invalid-ipa-missing-embedded-provisioning-profile-are-you-sure-this-is-an-ad-h)

Comment: Yes . I took it from release folder

Comment: could you please attach xcode screenshot

Comment: select **Generic iOS Device** & take build

Comment: Let me check with  Generic build. if it fails I will come with Screen shot

Comment: Please build by signing in as  a developer and build with Generic iOS Device option . If you are not signed in as a developer you will get Provisional file missing error

Comment: is your app running in the iPhone physical device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please build by signing in as a developer and build with Generic iOS Device option . If you are not signed in as a developer you will get Provisional file missing error

Answer (score 0):

Seem you did the archive using simulator as the target device. Please user "Generic iOS Device" and then create the archive.